# Java Callable -> start thread and wait

Tags: java, multithreading

i am new here so sorry if i put this into a wrong topic?

My question:

```
class TaskEol implements Callable<ArrayList<Coordinates>> {
        ArrayList<CoordinatesEolEwp> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();

        public ArrayList<Coordinates> call() throws Exception {
            new Thread (() -> {
                indicatorDatabaseAction.setVisible(true);
                coordinates = loadCoordinatesOutOfDatabase();
                indicatorDatabaseAction.setVisible(false);
            }).start();


            return coordinates;
        }
    }
```

how do i wait for the Database to write the coordinates in the object before returning it?

Comment: That's a pretty bad way to use `Callable`. It shouldn't start a thread, it should be given to an `Executor` to handle, which returns a `Future` that contains (eventually) the result.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer (wow!)... Could you give me a short exampe how to use this? Or should i do it in a complete other way? So i hope you can see the problem. I want to do some Databaseaction in a thread. (There will be 4 DAO-Actions at the same time) and i have to wait for the result

Answer (score 2):

Along these lines, where `myCallable` is your callable but without the `Thread` stuff, i.e.

```
public ArrayList<Coordinates> call() throws Exception {
    indicatorDatabaseAction.setVisible(true);
    coordinates = loadCoordinatesOutOfDatabase();
    indicatorDatabaseAction.setVisible(false);

    return coordinates;
}
```

then...

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<ArrayList<Coordinates>> f = e.submit(myCallable);

// Note that Future.get() blocks until results are ready
ArrayList<Coordinates> coords = f.get();
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but is then the ProcessIndicator is running?

Comment: Or should i use a complete other construct to do this? While the Databas-Action is running, the user should be able to use the programm. An ProcessIndicator should show that the database is loading data

Comment: Possibly. I don't know what your ProcessIndicator is, I just showed you how to use `Callable` properly. You still need to handle the eventual results somehow, possibly by polling `Future.isDone()`, or some other kind of mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, meant ProgressIndicator like: [ProgressIndicator](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/08d5121905196a3738d27d7bfc6c23a1fd8aa720/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6d6f6a6f636f72702f5150726f6772657373496e64696361746f722f6d61737465722f73637265656e2d636170747572652d312e706e67)

Comment: Actually i do not know if callable is the right construct to run my query

Comment: Maybe you want a `SwingWorker`?